# How do I include HTML content into the Bootstrap Popover's content option via GruntJS include-replace plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

Gday.

Well, maybe the solution is quite trivial, but I am not that much into JS and also couldn't find the issue @ include-replace GitHub page and on the web elsewhere.

**The task:**

I simply want to include the HTML content via Bootstrap Popover's content option by using the "include-replace" Grunt JS plugin.

**The code:**

```
   $('#foo').popover({
      html: 'true',
      title: 'Calendar',
      content: '@@include(\'includes/footer.html\')'
   });
```

**The result:**

I am simply shown the string in the popover's content:

`@@include('includes/footer.html')`

And now the contents of the "foo.html".

Any idea how to achive that?

**Lyrics**

I just don't wanna be editing the HTML file in the JS, beacuse the popover is going to be huge.

Comment: Sorry for rookie question, but what is `@@include` command intended to do?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin In GruntJS witn installed include-replace plugin this syntax basically takes the content from any .html file and includes it in the file where had been used. Just for the sake of code readability and dryness. It's basically the same as just copy-pasting the contents from "footer.html" directly to the content: ""

Comment: Does it return `html` content in form of a string? I mean would the following construction work - content: @@include(\'includes/footer.html\')? If not, what type `@@include` command actually returns?